# Is it better to JOIN using OR in the join condition or to use multiple JOINS

Tags: sql, performance, join, teradata

I'm trying to flag tickets based on whether they indicate a certain event has occurred. The issue I'm running into is that the particular value(s) that indicate such a condition occurred could be in any 1 of 25 fields on the ticket and my current logic takes quite a while to complete (generally >45min) if it completes at all (our DBAs ocassionally kill it for taking too much CPU or having too high a PJI). Currently I'm using the below to try and flag the tickets:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE
--DROP TABLE 
FCT
AS ( 
SELECT
I_FCT.Ticket_Nbr
, I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK
, I_FCT.S_DATE
, I_FCT.E_DATE

, CASE
    WHEN I_FCT.Event1_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '1'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event2_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '2'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event3_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '3'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event4_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '4'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event5_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '5'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event6_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '6'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event7_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '7'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event8_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '8'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event9_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '9'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event10_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '10'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event11_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '11'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event12_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '12'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event13_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '13'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event14_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '14'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event15_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '15'
    /*WHEN I_FCT.Event16_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '16'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event17_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '17'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event18_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '18'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event19_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '19'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event20_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '20'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event21_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '21'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event22_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '22'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event23_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '23'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event24_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '24'
    WHEN I_FCT.Event25_CK = AD.Event_CK THEN '25'*/
    ELSE NULL
END AS AOD_Event

FROM
I_FCT

LEFT JOIN AOD_CKS AS AD
    ON (AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event1_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event2_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event3_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event4_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event5_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event6_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event7_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event8_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event9_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event10_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event11_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event12_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event13_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event14_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event15_CK
        /*OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event16_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event17_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event18_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event19_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event20_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event21_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event22_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event23_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event24_CK
        OR AD.Event_CK = I_FCT.Event25_CK*/
    )
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (Ticket_Nbr) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

So my question is whether it would be better to switch to JOINing once per Event CK (which is a key value by the way & is the index on AOD_CKS)? Or should I go a little less verbose & try splitting up the work (i.e. join once for fields 1-6, another table for 7-13, etc.) & then JOIN those 4 tables together?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The _right_ answer is to denormalize your table rather than having 25 fields that all have similar meanings.  If you can't do that - yes I would split it into multiple queries and UNION them together.  Having indexes on all 25 fields would help the query, but may hurt updates and inserts, so you need to weigh the impact on the system as a whole.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of using a JOIN to merge the different results together. That way I maintain 1 record to each ticket. I would certainly love to denormalize and/or add additional indices to the table, but I don't have the proper permissions to alter most permanent tables. Anyway I'll give the multiple volatile table creation setup a shot & see how it goes.

Comment: Well, the right answer is to *normalize*  your table as it's heavily *denormalized*. Whenever you do an `OR`ed join condition you'll get a *product join*, there's no workaround. Try switching to 25 seperate SELECTs and `UNION` the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting the JOIN into 3 pieces and then merging the data as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                  FLAG ADDICTION CLAIMS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE
--DROP TABLE 
I_FCT_1
AS ( 
SELECT
    I_FCT.Claim_Nbr
    , I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK

    , CASE
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag1_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '1'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag2_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '2'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag3_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '3'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag4_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '4'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag5_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '5'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag6_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '6'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag7_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '7'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag8_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '8'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AOD_Diag

FROM
    I_FCT

    LEFT JOIN ADD_CKS AS AD
        ON (AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag1_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag2_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag3_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag4_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag5_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag6_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag7_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag8_CK
        )
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (Claim_Nbr) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE
--DROP TABLE 
I_FCT_2
AS ( 
SELECT
    I_FCT.Claim_Nbr
    , I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK

    , CASE
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag9_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '9'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag10_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '10'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag11_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '11'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag12_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '12'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag13_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '13'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag14_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '14'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag15_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '15'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag16_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '16'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AOD_Diag

FROM
    I_FCT

    LEFT JOIN ADD_CKS AS AD
        ON (AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag9_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag10_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag11_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag12_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag13_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag14_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag15_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag16_CK
        )
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (Claim_Nbr) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE
--DROP TABLE 
I_FCT_3
AS ( 
SELECT
    I_FCT.Claim_Nbr
    , I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK

    , CASE
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag17_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '17'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag18_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '18'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag19_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '19'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag20_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '20'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag21_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '21'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag22_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '22'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag23_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '23'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag24_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '24'
        WHEN I_FCT.Diag25_CK = AD.Diag_CK THEN '25'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AOD_Diag

FROM
    I_FCT

    LEFT JOIN ADD_CKS AS AD
        ON (AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag17_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag18_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag19_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag20_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag21_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag22_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag23_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag24_CK
            OR AD.Diag_CK = I_FCT.Diag25_CK
        )
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (Claim_Nbr) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE
--DROP TABLE 
FCT
AS ( 
SELECT
    I_FCT.Claim_Nbr
    , I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK
    , I_FCT.ADMISSION_DATE

    , I_FCT.DISCHARGE_DATE

    , I_FCT.ADMISSION_DATE_DIM_CK
    , I_FCT.Proc3_CK
    , I_FCT.Proc4_CK
    , I_FCT.Proc5_CK
    , I_FCT.Proc6_CK
    , I_FCT.Proc7_CK
    , I_FCT.Bill_Type
    , CASE
        WHEN C1.AOD_Diag IS NOT NULL THEN C1.AOD_Diag
        WHEN C2.AOD_Diag IS NOT NULL THEN C2.AOD_Diag
        WHEN C3.AOD_Diag IS NOT NULL THEN C3.AOD_Diag
        ELSE NULL
    END AS AOD_Diag

FROM
    I_FCT

    JOIN I_FCT_1 AS C1
        ON C1.Claim_Nbr = I_FCT.Claim_Nbr
            AND C1.Plan_Dim_CK = I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK

    JOIN I_FCT_2 AS C2
        ON I_FCT.Claim_Nbr = C2.Claim_Nbr
            AND I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK = C2.Plan_Dim_CK

    JOIN I_FCT_3 AS C3
        ON I_FCT.Claim_Nbr = C3.Claim_Nbr
            AND I_FCT.Plan_Dim_CK = C3.Plan_Dim_CK
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (Claim_Nbr)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: This is actually working better than your original query? You do 3 product joins instead of one, this should need 3 times more CPU. Did you check Explains?

Comment: This does work better. The # of `JOIN`s is the same, but fewer run at any one time since each `CREATE VOLATILE` runs in sequence, thus lowering the PJI, as well as CPU & Spool usage. The run time was drastically improved as well. I did not look at the Explain for either the old or new versions of the script since the estimates are generally nowhere near reality and aren't even consistently high or low (our DB is NOT well managed).

Comment: The estimates should be similar, but the actual join type should be a `product` join in both cases. If your DB is managed similar to your data model... :)